# class attributes by name

Tags: python, class

The parameter dictionary is passed to the class. Also declared class attributes. in a cycle, I assign a value to the class attributes by name, but it does not come out ... the getattr writes that there is no such attribute ... it completely fell into despondency ...

```py
def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master=parent)
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.__background = None 
        self.__foreground = None
        self.__master = parent
        self.__child = None
        self.__text = None
        self.__border = None
        self.__font = None
        self.__bordercolor = None
        self.__sticky = None
```

```py
for key in self.kwargs.keys():
            if key in CustomButton.__optionsList:
                self.__key = self.kwargs.get(key)
                # getattr(self,'__'+key) raise AttributeError: '__'+key not in class
            else:
                raise ValueError('Can\'t find the parameter: {0}'.format(key))
```

Comment: You seem to expect that assignment to `self.__key` somehow uses the *value* of `key`, rather than unconditionally referring to the attribute literally named `__key`.  Actually doing that would require `setattr(self, '__'+key, X)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of [Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

You can fix your code in two ways:

1. Change attribute names to have only one underscore at the beginning like `_master` instead of `__master`.
2. Use `getattr` with the name of the class: `getattr(self, '_' + self.__class__.__name__ + '__' + key)`

Comment: Now he began to swear at the type:
```python
TypeError: must be str, not type
```